# How do you apply multiple filters and sum in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of objects of the type Order

```
Order
 :status
 :amount
```

status can be **prepaid**, **postpaid** and **cancelled**

I want to get the sum of amount for each status. How do you do this in ruby?

Example:
If I have five orders

```
O1 - postpaid - 100
O2 - prepaid - 10
O3 - prepaid - 15
O4 - cancelled - 20
O5 - cancelled - 45
```

The Output should be a map that looks like this

```
{postpaid: 100, prepaid: 25, cancelled: 65}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
a = [[:post, 100],[:pre, 10], [:pre, 15],[:canc, 20],[:canc, 45]]
```

there are many wants to obtain the sums. Here's are two.

**Use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)**

The object is a hash, initialized with a default value of zero:

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(type,amt),h| h[type] += amt }
  #=> {:post=>100, :pre=>25, :canc=>65}
```

Here are the steps:

```
enum = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[:post, 100], [:pre, 10], [:pre, 15],
  #    [:canc, 20], [:canc, 45]]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can view the contents of the enumerator that are passed into the block by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) by converting the enumerator to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[:post, 100], {}], [[:pre, 10], {}], [[:pre, 15], {}],
  #    [[:canc, 20], {}], [[:canc, 45], {}]]
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to go through the calculations step-by-step:

```
(type,amt),h = enum.next
  #=> [[:post, 100], {}] 
type #=> :post 
amt  #=> 100 
h    #=> {} 
h[type] += amt
  #=> h[type] = h[type] + amt
  #=> h[:post] = h[:post] + 100
  #=> h[:post] = 0 + 100 # h[:post] on right set to default value
  #=> h[:post] = 100
```

```
(type,amt),h = enum.next
  #=> [[:pre, 10], {:post=>100}] 
h[type] += amt 
  #=> 10 

(type,amt),h = enum.next
  #=> [[:pre, 15], {:post=>100, :pre=>10}] 
h[type] += amt
  #=> 25 

(type,amt),h = enum.next
  #=> [[:canc, 20], {:post=>100, :pre=>25}] 
h[type] += amt
  #=> 20 

(type,amt),h = enum.next
  #=> [[:canc, 45], {:post=>100, :pre=>25, :canc=>20}] 
h[type] += amt
  #=> 65 

h
  #=> {:post=>100, :pre=>25, :canc=>65}
```

**Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

```
Hash[a.group_by(&:first)
      .values
      .map { |b| [b.first.first, b.reduce(0) {|tot,(_,amt)| tot+amt}]}]
  #=> {:post=>100, :pre=>25, :canc=>65}
```

The steps:

```
h = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {:post=>[[:post, 100]],
  #    :pre=> [[:pre, 10], [:pre, 15]],
  #    :canc=>[[:canc, 20], [:canc, 45]]}

c = h.values
  #=> [[[:post, 100]],
  #    [[:pre, 10], [:pre, 15]],
  #    [[:canc, 20], [:canc, 45]]]
```

`map` first passes the first element of `c` (an array containing one element, the array `[:post, 100]`) into the block and assigns it to the block variable:

```
b = [[:post, 100]]
[b.first.first, b.reduce(0) {|tot,(_,amt)| tot+amt}]
  #=> [[:post, 100].first, [[:post, 100]].reduce(0) {|tot,(_,amt)| tot+amt}]
  #=> [:post, 100]
```

`map` then passes the second element of `c` to the block:

```
b = [[:pre, 10], [:pre, 15]]
[b.first.first, b.reduce(0) {|tot,(_,amt)| tot+amt}]
  #=> [:pre, 25]
```

and so on. After all elements of `c` have been passed to the block, the mapped values are returned as an array:

```
d = [[:post, 100], [:pre, 25], [:canc, 65]]
```

The final step is to convert this to a hash:

```
Hash[d]
  #=> {:post=>100, :pre=>25, :canc=>65}
```

or in Ruby 2.0+:

```
d.to_h
  #=> {:post=>100, :pre=>25, :canc=>65}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a group_by and then map