# Turn a hash symbol to string and apply .ord method (for an offset)

Tags: ruby, hash

I am doing a coding exercise(just to clear up any questions beforehand). My objective is to be able to offset the hash key by a specified amount. The problem I am having is if the hash key is a symbol. My approach is to turn it into a string and go from there. Here is my code:

```
class :: Hash
  def transpose_key(offset) 

    self.each_key{|key|
      t = (key.to_s.ord - "a".ord + offset) 
      key = (t % 26) + "a".ord.chr 
      }
    return self
  end #def
end #class


wrong_keys = { :a => "rope", :b => "knife", :x => "life-jacket", :z => "raft" }

puts wrong_keys.transpose_key(2)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
test.rb:6:in `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
```

I'm confused because I would think (key.to_s.ord) would give me a string letter on which to convert to ascii? I will later add functionality for numbered keys. Most of all I would like to, if at possible, use the approach I have started and make it work. Any ideas?

UPDATED

Here is my new code:

```
def transpose(string, offset)
  #string = string.chars
  string.each_codepoint {|c| puts (c + offset)  > 122 ? (((c - 97) + offset) % 26 + 97).chr : (c + offset).chr}
end

transpose('xyz', 5)
```

...the output is correct, but it puts every character on different line. I have tried a various ways to try to join it, but can't seem to. If I use print in the iteration instead of puts, the output is joined, but I don't get a new line, which I want. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need some parentheses: `key = ((t % 26) + "a".ord).chr `,  but I see that's not enough.

Comment: I tried adding the parentheses, i see now how my syntax was incorrect there. as you said it wasn't enough so i broke the code down a little more :  `t= (key.to_s.ord - "a".ord + offset) 
      u = t % 26 
      key = (u + "a".ord).chr `        this exact code has worked before when i was doing a similar exercise on transposing strings by an offset. just cant seem to apply it to hashes correctly :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this gives you want you want:

```
class Hash
  def transpose_key(offset) 
    map do |key, value|
      t = (key.to_s.ord - "a".ord + offset) % 26 
      [(t + "a".ord).chr.to_sym, value] 
    end.to_h
  end
end

wrong_keys = { :a => "rope", :b => "knife", :x => "life-jacket", :z => "raft" }

puts wrong_keys.transpose_key(2)
  # {:c=>"rope", :d=>"knife", :z=>"life-jacket", :b=>"raft"}
```

[Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) (v2.0+) is an alternative to the class method [Hash::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) (v1.0+)for converting an array of two-element arrays to a hash:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
Hash[a] #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}
a.to_h  #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

If we removed `.to_h` from the method we would find that  the value returned by `map` (to which `to_h` is applied) is:

```
[[:c, "rope"], [:d, "knife"], [:z, "life-jacket"], [:b, "raft"]]
```

To use Hash#each_key, you could do this:

```
class Hash
  def transpose_key(offset) 
    each_key.with_object({}) do |key,h|
      t = (key.to_s.ord - "a".ord + offset) % 26 
      h[(t + "a".ord).chr.to_sym] = self[key] 
    end
  end
end

puts wrong_keys.transpose_key(2)
  # {:c=>"rope", :d=>"knife", :z=>"life-jacket", :b=>"raft"}
```

On reflection, I prefer the latter method.

Comment: that line below 't = '...... that is in the brackets, how doest that work? as far as the use of the brackets? is that the same as putting it all in one line but making it readable to Ruby?

Comment: also, i see you changed it to the map method. i'm cool with that. but i am also curious to know if it is because the hash method each_key had no way of working (perhaps because i needed 2 arguments rather than one to make this work)?

Comment: The brackets are to map each key to a two-element array. If you use `each_key`, you need a way to save the value computed in the block. I addressed both questions in an edit.

Comment: Ahhhh! I totally get it! Thanks Cary!!

Comment: ok wait...i don't TOTALLY get it...2 tiny things....i had to google the with_object method, it says "Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object" in this case, i see you specified the object with a hash sign ({}). 1) Does that mean the object is the whole hash itself? is that how the computed value is saved? 2) also, just so I'm clear, does the 'h' represent hash and so when it's used it kinda reads like -  hash[index's code]? Which then breaks the key into a 2 index array that looks like  ['old letter', 'new letter']??

Comment: [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) takes an argument equal to the initial value of an object, here an empty hash. The object is represented by the last block variable, here `h`. After all elements of the enumerator are passed to and processed by the block, the enumerator returns the object `h`, except `h` will no longer be empty.  For details of how the enumerator's elements are passed to the block, you may wish to read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022537/ruby-method-returns-void-value-expression).

Comment: By way of example (recall `offset #=> 2`), the first value passed to the block is `[:a, {}]`, so `key, h = [:a, {}]`, i.e., `key #=> :a` and `h #=> {}`. Then `t = (key.to_s.ord - "a".ord + offset) % 26 #=> (2 % 26) #=> 2`, so `h[(t + "a".ord).chr.to_sym] = self[key]  #=> h[(2+"a".ord).chr.to_sym] = self[:a] #=> h[:c] = "rope"`, so now `h #=> { :c=>"rope"}`.  After the next element is passed to and processed by the block, `h #=> { :c=>"rope", :d=>"knife"}` and so on.

Comment: perfect. thats pretty much what i though was going on, and your explanation confirms and expands on that. thanks! i will check out your other answer as well just for further understanding :)

Comment: i just saw your latest explanation, and it is AWESOME! Being so new (about 5 weeks now it think), it helps a lot when things are broken into little pieces for me, lol. I checked the link you provided but i don't see any comments from you? the topic/question is 'ruby method returns void value expression' and the code is for a palindrome...is that the correct link?

Comment: Wrong link. It should be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654578/how-do-you-apply-multiple-filters-and-sum-in-ruby).

Comment: loved it. made it a favorite in fact. you give super helpful answers and explanations

Comment: Thanks, happy to help. You have the right attitude of digging into an answer until you understand it thoroughly.  As you gain experience with Ruby, and give answers to Ruby questions on SO, being as thorough as you can will help you refine your own understanding of the details.

Comment: Ruby is a lot to process this early into it, but I'm totally determined to master it. When I'm better I will be helping others too :) I can't wait to be a Ruby rockstar (like you!)!!

Answer (score 3):

> I'm confused because I would think `(key.to_s.ord)`  would ...

That's the wrong line.

The next line is the line raising the error, and you're not doing `.to_s.ord`, you're doing `.ord.to_s`:

```
  key = (t % 26) + "a".ord.chr
```

`"a".ord.chr` has no meaning, you're converting a character to an ordinal and back to a character, and then trying to add an integer and a character, hence your error. Replace `"a".ord.chr` with `"a".ord`

Comment: your right I was missing parentheses it was supposed to be `key = ((t % 26) + "a".ord).chr` because i want to subtract the ordinal value 'a'  from (t% 26) and turn the result of that into a character. I am doing this (the entire block of code)  to wrap letters like 'z' with an offset of 3, back around to the beginning of the alphabet.