# Why does this Ruby method return a "void value expression" error?

Tags: ruby

I have this simple method

```
def is_palindrome?(sentence)
  raise ArgumentError.new('expected string') unless sentence.is_a?(String)
  safe_sentence = sentence.gsub(/\W+/, '').downcase
  return safe_sentence == safe_sentence.reverse
end

is_palindrome?"rails"
```

When I run it I get the error `void value expression` in line 4 which is the return statement

What's wrong here?

Comment: Even though your `return` can be and usually is omitted, I don't see a `void value expression`. Is this all the code in the file?

Comment: yes this the whole thing

Comment: And how do you run it?

Comment: I add is_palindrome?"something" to the bottom of the file

Comment: The code, as-s, works for me. Bottom of what file?

Comment: In your return line, try `return (safe_sentence == safe_sentence.reverse)` Or, as cremno pointed out, you can omit `return` altogether:   `safe_sentence == safe_sentence.reverse`

Comment: And how did you include the file?

Comment: @lurker, the file is called new.rb, so from the terminal I said ruby new.rb

Comment: When I run what you show in the question, as-is, with the new line, `ruby new.rb`, it just returns with no output (as expected, since it doesn't print anything to the terminal). If I just replace your last line with, `is_palindrome?"rails" ? puts 'true' : puts 'false'`, I get 'false'.

Comment: @lurker for me it returns the error void value expression. Very strange

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: Please make sure the posted code is exactly the same as the content of `new.rb`. Maybe you have two different `new.rb`.

Comment: @lurker ruby 2.1.2p95 ...

Comment: @cremno it's the exact copy

Comment: What operating system are you running on? I did a copy/paste from your posted code to a file on Linux. I've seen posts where odd, non-visible characters creep in one way or the other, but don't copy over. I tried your code with 2.1.0 and 2.2.0 (I don't happen to have 2.1.2p95 installed), and both worked fine. Maybe a silly request, but try copying/pasting the file from your question back to a new `rb` file and see what happens.

Comment: Ok will try that, I am running yosemite @lurker

Comment: I am able to reproduce your error message when I do not have a newline after `downcase` but instead use spaces to make it wrap to the next line on the screen. Verify that each line is really on a separate line. Also, try putting a semi-colon after each of the 3 lines in the function to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is long overdue but I noticed that this question didn't have an answer, as I was researching this exact same problem. I got the same kind of error not to long ago, what this error means is that Ruby is trying find a `conditions change` within your code and can't find it. This could be because Ruby isn't reading your code properly, or it could be because there's a bug somewhere. Fixing it is actually extremely easy.

```
def is_palindrome?(sentence)
  raise ArgumentError.new('expected string') unless sentence.is_a?(String)#<= Right here at 'unless' condition is changed
  safe_sentence = sentence.gsub(/\W+/, '').downcase
  return safe_sentence == safe_sentence.reverse
end

is_palindrome?"rails"
```

For some reason your version of Ruby is trying to find the condition change and defaulting to the original condition, *it took a lot of research to come up with this*.

So how do you fix this? The quick answer is to add an `if/else statement` instead of an `unless`:

```
def is_palindrome?(word)      
  to_rev = word.split('')
  rev_arr = to_rev.reverse
  new_word = rev_arr.join('')
  if new_word == word
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

is_palindrome?("racecar") #<= Returns true
is_palindrome?("test") #<= Returns false
```

If you wanted to use your regex:

```
def is_palindrome?(sentence)
  new_sentence = sentence.gsub(/\W+/, '').downcase.reverse
  if new_sentence == sentence.downcase
    return true
  elsif new_sentence != sentence.downcase
    return false
  else
    raise ArgumentError.new("String expected, instead found #{sentence}")
  end
end

is_palindrome?("racecar") #<= Returns true
is_palindrome?("test") <= Returns false
```

*This is completely untested* but you get the idea. This will add a change in conditions and will allow Ruby to realize that there is a change in the conditions.

---

Now why is your system outputting this? The short answer again is, nobody really knows, could be your system has a bug in it, could be that your version of Ruby somewhere is corrupted.

A couple things you can try:

1. Reinstall the latest version of Ruby
2. Go into the Ruby files within your system and check for anything that doesn't belong
3. Move your directory to somewhere that is guaranteed to run with Ruby, IE into the Ruby directory itself. (*This really shouldn't be an issue*)
4. Check your CPU usage, running program, etc., to see if there's anything that could be messing with your system
5. ***LAST RESORT*** Hard reboot your system don't do this unless you absolutely have to, IE you find a virus that can't be wiped without you rebooting.

The reason people are unable to reproduce this error is probably because nobody can really see the way you're running the program, maybe you have a different version of Linux, or Windows, whatever. Hope this answered your question..

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question when I was trying to return evaluated boolean in return statement:

```
return x==1 or x==2
```

It turns out that ruby need brackets:

```
return (x==1 or x==2)
```

Comment: Ah.  I think using `||` instead of `or` would do the trick too, since that has a higher precedence.